# Numpy install requirement on package fails on pip install from PyPI but not from .whl

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I recently build my first python package and tried to test distribution with test.pypi.org ([Github repo](https://github.com/oliverm91/mathsom) [Test PyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/mathsom/))

Code for building the dist:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Code for uploading to Test PyPI:

```
twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

Then I created and empty conda env to test the installation with:

```
conda create --prefix ./envs --no-default-packages python=3.6
```

In this enviroment I used **succesfully** pip install with wheel file:

```
pip install mathsom-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

But if I try to install it from Test PyPI numpy installation fails (it is in install_requirements en setup.cfg file). Code:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mathsom
```

Setup.cfg code:

```
[metadata]
name = mathsom
author = Oliver Mohr B.
author_email = oliver.mohr.b@gmail.com
version = 0.1.1
description = Personal library for math related problems
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/oliverm91/mathsom
license_files = LICENSE
keywords = solvers, solver, interpolations, interpolation, numerics, derivatives, integrals

[options]
package_dir=
    = src
packages=find:
setup_requires = 
    numpy
install_requires =
    numpy
    scipy

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

First lines of error (extremly long error msg):
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages, always copy/paste the content into your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your error message, you can see

```
Downloading ... mathsom-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

So it is also using a whl file. However, the way numpy is installed differs. In your error message, it is clear that `numpy` is trying to compile from source, which is not suprising, since you set the index to `https://test.pypi.org/simple/` and there is [only source distributions of numpy under that index](https://test.pypi.org/simple/numpy/). If you allow that the dependencies can be pulled from pypi, by setting test.pypi as an extra-index with `--extra-index-url` then everything works (tested in a fresh conda env created with the command you have provided):

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mathsom
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting mathsom
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/b3/76e6bbaa6c1da9f6f032e114af7f5724077154a28b5fc7069330185f2bc8/mathsom-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.5.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (31.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 31.2 MB 393 kB/s
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (13.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.2 MB ...
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, mathsom
Successfully installed mathsom-0.1.1 numpy-1.19.5 scipy-1.5.4
```

Comment: Thanks, will `--extra-index-url` be needed in official PyPI server? or should I add some extra fields on my setup.cfg file to avoid using it and do a simple `pip install mathsom`

Comment: `pip install mathsom` works without `--extra-index-url` if the package you are trying to install and all its dependencies can be found on the official pypi server